# Insert references from Endnote into a Keynote presentation

Tags: keynote

In PowerPoint for Windows it is possible to insert references directly from Endnote into PowerPoint. As far as I can tell, this feature is not supported on the macOS version of PowerPoint. Anyhow, I prefer Keynote, but it would make my life much easier if I could directly insert formatted references from Endnote (according to the different templates that exists in Endnote) into my Keynote presentations. Is this possible? If not, is anyone aware of any good work-arounds for this?

I can do it manually with first saving the reference to MS Word and then copy/paste the reference into Keynote, but obviously I would prefer a direct method.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Are you able to edit your question to provide an example of what *correctly formatted references* look like? And, if possible, explain what you've tried so far and how the formatting differs?

Comment: From Endnote's documentation it seems they only support PPT for Windows, not PPT for macOS or Keynote.  You could reach out to the developer with a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

From [EndNote's documentation](http://endnote.com/product-details/compatibility) it seems they only support PowerPoint for Windows, not PowerPoint for macOS or Keynote. You could reach out to the developer of Endnote with a [feature request](http://endnote.com/contact).

From the website:

> **Presentation support**
>   * Microsoft PowerPoint® for Windows 2007, 2010*, 2013*, 2016*
>
> *32-bit and 64-bit

As for Macintosh software supported, they do not list *any* presentation software.

[Macintosh compatibility and system requirements](http://endnote.com/product-details/compatibility#macintosh) from EndNote's support site.